# Storing Word Line and Frequency based on Word

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, frequency, cpu-word

I am working on a problem, in which I have to be able to read a text file, and count the frequency and line number of a specific word.

So for example, a txt file that reads

```
"Hi my name is

Bob. This is 

Cool"
```

Should return:

```
1 Hi 1

1 my 1

1 name 1

2 is 1 2

1 bob 2

1 this 2

1 cool 3
```

I am having trouble deciding how to store the line number, as well as the word frequency. I have tried a few different things, and so far this is where I am at.

Any help?

```
        Dictionary<string, int> countDictionary = new Dictionary<string,int>();
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> lineDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

        List<string> lines = new List<string>();


        System.IO.StreamReader file =
                new System.IO.StreamReader("Sample.txt");

        //Creates a List of lines
        string x;
        while ((x = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            lines.Add(x);
        }

        foreach(var y in Enumerable.Range(0,lines.Count()))
        {
            foreach(var word in lines[y].Split())
            {
                if(!countDictionary.Keys.Contains(word.ToLower()) && !lineDictionary.Keys.Contains(word.ToLower()))
                {
                    countDictionary.Add(word.ToLower(), 1);
                    //lineDictionary.Add(word.ToLower(), /*what to put here*/);
                }
                else
                {
                    countDictionary[word] += 1;
                    //ADD line to dictionary???
                }
            }
        }



       foreach (var pair in countDictionary)//WHAT TO PUT HERE to print both 
       {
           Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", pair.Value, pair.Key);
       }

        file.Close();


        System.Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What if a word appears in a line twice?  Should that line number be in the list of lines where it appears twice?  If yes, then you could get the frequency from the length of that list and not need a second dictionary to keep track of the frequency.

Comment: Im a little confused by your question.

If a word appears in a line a second time, it would not do anything.

Comment: @LeviJ: Presumably you would want to at least increase the word count.  You may also want to note the line number a second time, or you may not (depending on the requirements).

Answer (score 3):

You can pretty much do this with one line of linq

```
var processed =
  //get the lines of text as IEnumerable<string> 
  File.ReadLines(@"myFilePath.txt")
    //get a word and a line number for every word
    //so you'll have a sequence of objects with 2 properties
    //word and lineNumber
    .SelectMany((line, lineNumber) => line.Split().Select(word => new{word, lineNumber}))
    //group these objects by their "word" property
    .GroupBy(x => x.word)
    //select what you need
    .Select(g => new{
        //number of objects in the group
        //i.e. the frequency of the word
        Count = g.Count(), 
        //the actual word
        Word = g.Key, 
        //a sequence of line numbers of each instance of the 
        //word in the group
        Positions = g.Select(x => x.lineNumber)});

foreach(var entry in processed)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
                      entry.Count,
                      entry.Word,
                      string.Join(" ",entry.Positions));
}
```

I like 0 based counting, so you may want to add 1 in the appropriate place.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I'm trying to break your program down and understand it, not just copy it.

Answer (score 1):

You are tracking two different properties of the entity "word" in two separate data structures.  I would suggest creating a class to represent that entity, something like

```
public class WordStats
{
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public List<int> AppearsInLines { get; set; }
    public Word()
    {
        AppearsInLines = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Then track things in a

```
Dictionary<string, WordStats> wordStats = new Dictionary<string, WordStats>();
```

Use the word itself as the key.  When you encounter a new word, check whether there is already an instance of Word with that specific key.  If so, get it and update the Count and AppearsInLines property; if not create a new instance and add it to the dictionary.

```
foreach(var y in Enumerable.Range(0,lines.Count()))
{
    foreach(var word in lines[y].Split())
    {
        WordStats wordStat;
        bool alreadyHave = words.TryGetValue(word, out wordStat);
        if (alreadyHave)
        {
            wordStat.Count++;
            wordStat.AppearsInLines.Add(y);
        }
        else
        {
            wordStat = new WordStats();
            wordStat.Count = 1;
            wordStat.AppearsInLines.Add(y);
            wordStats.Add(word, wordStat);
        }
```

Comment: So, in my Dictionary declaration, what would my Value be?

Comment: The Value is the type Word.  Added a more detailed example.  Also changed the name of the class to avoid confusion and the syntax error you note.